# Calculate the derivative of $g(x)=x^2.cos(1/x^2)$. Does the derivative of this function exist at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus

Calculate the derivative of $g(x)=x^2.cos(1/x^2)$.  Does the derivative of this function exist at $x=0$?

I calculated the derivative to be $2.cos(1/x^2)x+2(sin(1/x^2))/x$.

I'm tempted to say that the derivative does not exist at zero because it is a vertical line, but I'm not sure this is the case.

Comment: Yes, the limit as $x$ tends to zero from both directions of $f'(x)$ are $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. So $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Note that your function $g(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$, therefore neither is its derivative. A necessary condition for the derivative to exist at a point is to the function be defined and to be continuos at that point, which is not the case.

Comment: As simple as that. Nice. +1

Answer (score -1):

$g'$ does not have limit in $0$, but it does not mean $g$ not differentiable in $0$ :
$$\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=x\cos\frac{1}{x^2}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0$$
so $g'(0)=0$.

All you can say is that $g'$ is not continuous in $0$.

Comment: As the other answer mentions, the function itself isn't even defined at $\;x=0\;$ so it can **not** be differentiable there ...

Comment: If it's not continuous at $0$ then it's not differentiable there by contrapositive. A function not continuous at a point is never differentiable at a point. In addition, the function isn't defined there, let alone continuous

Comment: @Kernel_Dirichlet : I supposed the function was prolonged by continuity in $0$. And I didn't say $f$ was not continuous in $0$, I said $f'$ wasn't...